# Почему не засчитался знак Академик?

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, знаки, репутация

Заработать минимум 200 баллов репутации (максимальный результат за день) за один день. Хотя в своей статистике ясно вижу что 2 дня назад было заработано 294 репутации за день, но знак не дали?

Comment: Почему нельзя слишком короткий вопрос запостить: [Непонятные сообщения системы для слишком короткого заголовка и текста](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550)

Comment: да, на это обращали внимание уже человек 10 )) Проблема в том, что фильтр – где-то в движке сайта и его логику не очень просто поменять. (нужно ставить задачу разработчикам и это может повлиять на другие сайты). Однако, мы можем придумать более понятную формулировку – это задача попроще и локализация в наших руках.

Comment: Уже думала отдельным вопросом оформлять, да ладно :)

Comment: а что касается знака – ничего страшного, еще получится )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас 100 баллов из 295 за тот день были присуждены за ассоциацию учётных записей. К сожалению, согласно [ответу на Мете En.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287300/3212712) эти 100 баллов не учитываются.

Таким образом вам не хватило всего 5 баллов в тот злополучный день. Сочувствую(

Comment: Недавно вот [отсюда](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26224524#26224524) в чате это обсуждали.

Comment: Как будто если вас выбрать, знак засчитается.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет конечно) Но почему бы не совместить помощь в пользовании сайтом с изящной агитацией? =)

Comment: Да, были у меня такие подозрения, расстройства особого нет что нет значка -но есть расстройство от неточного описания.

Comment: @Mira, прекрасно вас понимаю. Описание, кстати, ввело меня, также, в заблуждение относительно единоразовости этого значка. Особенно с учётом того, что есть значки за 50 и 150 раз по 200 репутации в день.

Comment: Призыв к голосованию не относится к ответу. Уберите пожалуйста.

Comment: @KromStern, правилами, насколько я понял, это не запрещается. Но против вашей правки возражать не буду.

Comment: Не запрещается, но и к ответу не относится. Думаете откуда у вас 6 минусов? К сожалению у меня недостаточно репутации для предложения правок к ответам.

Comment: @KromStern, ну, я потому и пометил `P.S.`. Я согласен, что не относится. Но т.к. в правилах не запрещено и  не нашёл иного способа себя легально (с моей точки зрения легально) прорекламировать, то и решил добавить это. А помимо 6 минусов есть и 3 плюса. Буду, засим, считать, что мой рейтинг на выборах будет около 33% =)

Comment: @Kromster, итак, спустя два с чем-то года пришёл я и наконец-то выполнил вашу просьбу.